# How do I run several codes at once?

Tags: excel, vba, olap

I work with OLAP Cubes and have created code on several occasions for different purposes but now I would like to combine several functions, how do I succeed with that?

This is what I need help putting together. I am a real beginner and have solved most things through google before but now I cant find anything that I understand or that helps me.

1)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address <> "$A$5" Then Exit Sub
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
            pt.PivotFields("[Casino].[Casino].[Casino]").CurrentPageName = "[Casino].[Casino].&[" & Format(ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 1).Value, "") & "]"
            pt.PivotFields
        Next pt
    Next ws
    GoTo Sluta
Fel:
    MsgBox "Något gick fel :("
Sluta:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

2. 

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address <> "$A$3" Then Exit Sub
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
            pt.PivotFields("[Date].[Month Number].[Month Number]").CurrentPageName = "[Date].[Month Number].&[" & Format(ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 1).Value, "") & "]"
            pt.PivotFields
        Next pt
    Next ws
    GoTo Sluta
Fel:
    MsgBox "Något gick fel :("
Sluta:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

3. 

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address <> "$A$2" Then Exit Sub
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
            pt.PivotFields("[Date].[Year].[Year]").CurrentPageName = "[Date].[Year].&[" & Format(ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).Value, "") & "]"
            pt.PivotFields
        Next pt
    Next ws
    GoTo Sluta
Fel:
    MsgBox "Något gick fel :("
Sluta:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Write everything in one procedure and do not repeat your code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim PivFld As String
    Dim PageName As String

    On Error GoTo Fel
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Select Case Target.Address
    Case "$A$5"
        PivFld = "[Casino].[Casino].[Casino]"
        PageName = "[Casino].[Casino].&[" & Format(ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 1).Value, "") & "]"
    Case "$A$3"
        PivFld = "[Date].[Month Number].[Month Number]"
        PageName = "[Date].[Month Number].&[" & Format(ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 1).Value, "") & "]"
    Case "$A$2"
        PivFld = "[Date].[Year].[Year]"
        PageName = "[Date].[Year].&[" & Format(ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).Value, "") & "]"
    Case Else
        Exit Sub
    End Select

    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        Dim pt As PivotTable
        For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
            pt.PivotFields(PivFld).CurrentPageName = PageName
            pt.PivotFields
        Next pt
    Next ws
    
    GoTo Sluta
Fel:
    MsgBox "Något gick fel :("
Sluta:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Note that `On Error Resume Next` hides all error messages and you will never know if something goes wrong. Instead use `On Error GoTo Fel` and at least you get informed that something went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can combine all the ones into a single code and use if-statements for the differences:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim fields As String
Dim pageName as String
If Target.Address = "$A$5" Then fields="[Casino].[Casino].[Casino]": pageName = "[Casino].[Casino].&["
If Target.Address = "$A$3" Then fields="[Date].[Month Number].[Month Number]": pageName = "[Date].[Month Number].&["
If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then fields="[Date].[Year].[Year]": pageName = "[Date].[Year].&["
If fields = "" Then Exit Sub
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
pt.PivotFields(fields).CurrentPageName = pageName & Format(Target.Value, "") & "]"
pt.PivotFields
Next pt
Next ws
GoTo Sluta
Fel:
MsgBox "Något gick fel :("
Sluta:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Also adding variables fields and pageName to simplify.

Comment: I can not explain how happy I am right now, thank you very much